# Unable to call functions of a copied JS object

Tags: javascript, function, object, copy

I'm creating a copy of a JS object in order to perform functions on the copy. However, I'm unable to call the functions in the copied object, I just get an error saying that the functions do not exist in this instance, any ideas?

edit: here is the code

```
obj.isGridStateSolvable();
let tempobj = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
tempobj.isGridStateSolvable();
```

Line one is working correctly and the function is accessible however the third line is not.

edit 2: here is a testable example

```
class Num{
    constructor(numParam){
        this.number = numParam;
    }

    incrementNum(){
        this.number++;
    }
}

var num1 = new Num(5);
num1.incrementNum();

console.log(num1); //Outputs 6 as expected

let num2 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, num1);
num2.incrementNum();    //This function does not exist
```

Comment: `I'm creating a copy of a JS object in order to perform functions on the copy.` how did you make the copy? `any ideas` if you did the `JSON.stringify` -> `JSON.parse`, then that's your problem. There is no functions in JSON, so the "copy" won't have them after being made into that format.

Comment: Could you add a code-snippet to your question containing the code you're using to copy the object, please?

Comment: I forgot to add the code haha, updated now

Comment: [I cannot reproduce that.](https://jsbin.com/suyurakere/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: I have added a simple example that conveys my problem

Comment: With the new example - `num2` doesn't have the same prototype as `num1`.

Comment: so would I have to do something like this? var num3 = new Num(9);
num3 = num1; which would assign num3 the value of num1 in the same format?

Comment: You [can write your own clone function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) and make sure you also do `Object.getPrototypeOf(source)` then `Object.setPrototypeOf(target, sourcePrototype)`. It's more generic, since you can use it for any kind of object. However, with this example you have, I'd probably add a `clone` method that may just do `return new Num(this.number)` but it might also set other properties. It's probably better as not all things might be copyable via a generic clone function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JS spread.

```
let tempobj = { ...obj };
```

It is a new feature from ES and works very well for JS objects copying.

Answer (score 0):

There are several projects on npm which will copy the state of an object in JS into a new destination class/module, meaning the functions will be available.

here is a few

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dboneslabs/mpr - (i created this one) this does a deep copy, but you need to inform the library of the structure of your prototype/class/module
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfdc - i have not used  it but it mentioned prototype